# Javascript - Ocultar DIV al llegar a 0 (cero)

Tags: javascript

Los aprendices en JS tenemos un serio problema con las llaves y condicionales.

No puedo ocultar **el div pagar** cuando el contador llega **a cero** después de restar.

Todo me funciona muy bién, pero cuando llego a cero, el div pagar no se pone en **display none**...

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal aquí...?
¿Dónde está mi fallo...?

Muchas gracias...

```js
        var clicks=0;function clickME(){clicks += 1;document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks}
        var clicksdos=0;function clickME2(){clicksdos += 1;document.getElementById("clicksdos").innerHTML=clicksdos;
    
        if (clicksdos === 1) {
            document.getElementById("pagar").style.display = "block";
          }
    }
    
        if (clicksdos === 0) {
          document.getElementById("pagar").style.display = "none";
    }
    
        function restar() {
            if (clicks>0) clicks -= 1;
            document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks;
    }
    
        function restardos() {
        if (clicksdos>0) clicksdos -= 1;
        document.getElementById("clicksdos").innerHTML=clicksdos;
    
    };
```

```html
    <div id="clicks">0</div>
    <div id="clicksdos">0</div>
        
    <div class="comprar" onClick="clickME();clickME2();">Comprar</div>
        
    <div class="borrar" onClick="restar();restardos();">X</div>
        
    <div id="pagar">Pagar</div>
```

Comment: Tu codigo esta muy desordenado, ademas no necesitas llamar dos funciones por cada click, puedes hacer todo en una funcion.  Tambien necesitas una sola variable para llevar el conteo de clicks.

Comment: Ademas para que funcione como quieres, necesitas chequear el valor de la variable dentro de la funcion.

Comment: Claro. Es lo que tenemos los principiantes... Ya lo ordenaré cuando aprenda más, de momento intento ocultar el div "PAGAR" cuando el contador llegue a cero después de restar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás colocando mal el ocultar el div, debe de estar en la funcion restardos() y aplicando un `if` al momento de que llegue a 0 se oculte el div de **Pagar**.

```js
        var clicks=0;function clickME(){clicks += 1;document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks}
        var clicksdos=0;function clickME2(){clicksdos += 1;document.getElementById("clicksdos").innerHTML=clicksdos;
    
        if (clicksdos === 1) {
            document.getElementById("pagar").style.display = "block";
          }
    }
    
        if (clicksdos === 0) {
          document.getElementById("pagar").style.display = "none";
    }
    
        function restar() {
            if (clicks>0) clicks -= 1;
            document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=clicks;
    }
    
        function restardos() {
        if (clicksdos>0) clicksdos -= 1;
        document.getElementById("clicksdos").innerHTML=clicksdos;
if(clicksdos === 0){
document.getElementById("pagar").style.display = "none";
}

    
    };
```

```html
    <div id="clicks">0</div>
    <div id="clicksdos">0</div>
        
    <div class="comprar" onClick="clickME();clickME2();">Comprar</div>
        
    <div class="borrar" onClick="restar();restardos();">X</div>
        
    <div id="pagar">Pagar</div>
```

Comment: Es lo que decía... "Algo estoy haciendo mal" ... Muchas gracias! +10!

Comment: No hay porque, buen día compañero! :D